# firebase firestore compound query

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

```
UserTable
---------
Username
Age
Gender
countryA
countryB
CityA
CityB
```

country = Italty ,city = Jhb;

Want to achieve below by querying to firestore

```
if(country==countryA || country == countryB){
    
    if(city == CityA || city == CityB){
        //TODO
        return the document;
    }
}
```

Trying to achieve above  by querying to firestore

```
CollectionReference colRef = fireStore.collection("UserTable");

colRef.whereEqualTo("countryA",country).get();
colRef.whereEqualTo("countryB",country).get();
   
colRef.whereEqualTo("CityA",city).get();
colRef.whereEqualTo("CityB",city).get();
```

What do i code next?

How do I combine queries to achieve a success results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your document looks like this:

```
$user (document)
 |
 --- Username: "Kennedy"
 |
 --- Age: 20
 |
 --- Gender: "male"
 |
 --- Country: "USA"
 |
 --- City: "NY"
```

The follwing logic makes sense to be used:

```
if(country==countryA || country == countryB)
```

As it means that you want to perform an OR query. This can be achieved in Java up to ten elements using:

```
colRef.whereIn("Country", Arrays.asList("countryA", "countryB"));
```

However, there is a constraint. You **cannot** add another:

```
.whereIn("City", Arrays.asList("CityA", "CityA"));
```

Since you can use [at most one `whereIn` clause per query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#query_limitations). To solve this, you have to use the first query and filter the cities in the client.

Back to your initial queries:

```
colRef.whereEqualTo("countryA",country).get();
colRef.whereEqualTo("countryB",country).get();
   
colRef.whereEqualTo("CityA",city).get();
colRef.whereEqualTo("CityB",city).get();
```

I see that you are using different fields for "countryA" and "countryB", as well as for "CityA" and "CityB", ending in having a schema that looks like this:

```
$user (document)
 |
 --- Username: "Kennedy"
 |
 --- Age: 20
 |
 --- Gender: "male"
 |
 --- countryA: "A"
 |
 --- CityA: "A"
 |
 --- CountryB: "B"
 |
 --- CityB: "B"
```

This also means that those queries don't help you perform an OR operation. So most likely you should consider using the first database schema and perform a `whereIn()` query and filter the results in memory.

Comment: Thanks Alex, exactly I'm using schema 2 and I want user to have countryA & B fields in the collection similar to cities ,so is there anyway to approach since where queries can't apply.

Comment: No, using the second database schema it's not possible. Check also this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56865294/nosql-model-structure/56869041#56869041) out. So the recommended way is to change the structure of the document as mentioned in the first solution. Ok?

Comment: Thanks alex the link you provided really helpful.